# Bluetooth option not found on an ICS device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth

I have Android 4.0.4 (ICS) and the system report app says that it supports bluetooth. However this isn't shown in the settings for wifi etc. Is there any way of turning bluetooth on?

Comment: To help, we need more info. What is your device model?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you go to "Settings", the first section should be "Wireless & Networks". Under that, I have "Wi-Fi" (ON/OFF), "Bluetooth" (ON/OFF) followed by Data Usage. How does that look on your phone? If Bluetooth is not there, I don't think the ROM you are running recognizes your ability to run Bluetooth (if you do indeed have that ability).

What device and what ROM are you running?

Comment: I have used an app called root browser which shows that there is a folder for bluetooth in the rom and also an app called android assistant which says that bluetooth is supported. My system is described as: softwinners SoftwinerEvb, version Android 4.0.4, CPU 1,01 Ghz. CPU identifier shows this as Boxchip Allwinner A13 1,008Ghz and Tablet type Android Share MID/Haipad A13 Tablet.

Comment: "I have used an app called root browser which shows that there is a folder for bluetooth in the rom" you do realize that this has nothing to do with the capability of your device running bluetooth? This page does not list bluetooth at all: http://www.dhgate.com/product/cheapest-512mb-4gb-haipad-a13-mid-tablet/137910125.html — I don't understand where you get the notion from that your device supports bluetooth in the first place, can you refer something you've seen or read?

Comment: I was just assuming that if both these apps show bluetooth support then it should be possible to use it.

Comment: I was just assuming that if both these apps show bluetooth support then it should be possible to use it. By the way I am not using the original firmware. I flashed FaaastJB-V2 which is what it is running at the moment. I don't know if this makes a difference? I am a bit of a newbie to android so please make allowances if some of my questions seem simple.

Comment: I was just assuming that if both these apps show bluetooth support then it should be possible to use it. By the way I am not using the original firmware. I flashed FaaastJB-V2 which is what it is running at the moment. I don't know if this makes a difference? I am a bit of a newbie to android so please make allowances if some of my questions seem simple. PS. I meant to add that I am talking about using a USB dongle for bluetooth as the tablet supports OTG USB.